# Gadgets such as the smartphone vs Gadgets such as a smartphone

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

> "Electronic gadgets such as the smartphone, *the* laptop, and the 3D printer have drastically increased work productivity."

Why does the sentence use *the* not *a* if it wants to speak generally about smartphones or laptops ?

Does the sentence use *the* here because it speaks about three distinctive groups of gadgets ?

Source:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fj7yVGVUc-w

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This sentence uses **"the"** to convey *the idea or class of each kind of item*, or to allude to *the properties of each of these kinds of items*. Alternately, one could substitute: "...such as smartphones, laptops, and 3D printers..." for the same meaning.

Using **"a"** would imply that *one single* smartphone, laptop and 3D printer have drastically increased work productivity.

Answer (score 1):

The definite article (*the*) is used because the reference is to smartphones/laptops/3D printers generally, and as a member of the class "electronic gadgets." Consider this definition (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**the**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/the)
>   DETERMINER
>
> **3** Used to make a generalized reference to something rather than
>   identifying a particular instance:
>   *"he taught himself to play the violion"*
>   *"I worry about the future"*
>
> > **3.1** Used with a singular noun to indicate that it represents a whole
> >     species or class:
> >     *"they placed the African elephant on their endangered list"*

You would only use the indefinite article (*a* or *an*) here if you were talking about an actual instance of one of those devices, especially if the quantity is one. Consider this definition:

> [**a<sup>1</sup>**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/a) (also **an**)
>   DETERMINER
>
> **1** Used when mentioning someone or something for the first time in a text
>   or conversation:
>   *"a man came out of the room"*
>   *"it has been an honour to meet you"*
>
> > **1.1** Used with units of measurement to mean one such unit:
> >     *"a hundred"*
> >     *"a quarter of an hour"*

For example, the indefinite article is appropriate in the following sentence, but the definite article is not:

> Nowadays, most people carry **a** smartphone.

Comment: Thank you so much LMS , so what I have got now is when we think of smartphons as a class or a member of higher class we use "the" and when we think of a smartphone as one smartphone we use "a" ... is that correct ?

Comment: In this context, yes. Smartphones are a member of the class of electronic gadgets.